# How do I create a schema dynamically to store the folder structure?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to MongoDB, and I'm trying to design the schema structure for storing the folder hierarchy.

This is my schema design:

```
parent: {
   id: Schema.Object,
   title: String,
   children: []
}
```

Above children will store details dynamically in the following manner.
The id will refer to folder schema which has folder details.

```
children:[
    {
       id: Schema.Object,
       title : String,
       children:[
          {
             id:Schema.Object,
             titile: String
          }
       ]
    }
]
```

The above method is working fine. But I'm facing an issue on updating the title for a particular Id will be quiet complex. Is there any other way to design schema. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think nesting of `children` is not a proper approach to achieve this.

Rather you can introduce a new `key` for `children`, `level` this will help in 
  identifying the structure/hierarchy.

```
children:[
      {
         id:Schema.Object,
         titile: String,
         level: Number
      }
   ]
```

eg: abc/bcd/egt/something

abc(root) - level 0

bcd - level 1

egt - level 2

something - level 3

It will be dynamic and easy to maintain.

Comment: Thank you, Abhishek. I've stored the child ID instead of level. It worked for me.